# Output database variable with multiple line breaks

Tags: php

I've read about the nl2br() command but they echo out the variable to make it work but my variable is inside a list that I echo out.
Should I somehow put the nl2br() command in my if statement where I'm setting up the output or should I be looking somewhere else for my answer.

I have made 2 extra detail variables to output so I get 3 lines of text for the description of my product but there has to be a better way of doing it than that. I would think 1 detail variable with all the info would be the preferred way of doing it

I have tried to search for it but I'm afraid I'm just not asking the right question so any help in the right direction is appreciated.

```
<?php require_once './connections/connect_mysqli.php';
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 6 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
$i = 0;
$flatlist = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $details = $row["details"];
    $details2 = $row["details2"];
    $details3 = $row["details3"];
    $price = $row["price"];


    if ($i % 4 == 0) { 
        $flatlist .='<tr><td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>
        <p style=color:blue font-size=14px;>' . $product_name . '</p><br/>
            <p style=font-size:14px;>' . $details . '</p><br /> 
            ' . $details2 . '<br /> 
            ' . $details3 . '<br /> 
            <p style=font-size:14px;>$' . $price . '</p><br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><input type="button" value="Order" style=color:blue></a></td>';

    } else {

        $flatlist .= '<td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>
        <p style=color:blue font-size=14px;>' . $product_name . '</p><br />
            <p style=font-size:14px;>' . $details . '</p><br />
            ' . $details2 . '<br /> 
            ' . $details3 . '<br /> 
             <p style=font-size:14px;>$' . $price . '</p><br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><input type="button" value="Order" style=color:blue></a></td>';
    }
    $i++;
}
$flatlist .= '</tr></table>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Flats</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php require 'includes/skyline.php'; ?>
<?php require 'includes/menu.php'; ?>
<table width="1200" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <?php echo $flatlist ?>
   </tr>    
</table>
<?php require 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to point out you close the details `<p>` before the 2nd and 3rd lines. You probably want to close that after third line.

```
        <p style=font-size:14px;>' . $details . '<!-- remove here: </p> --><br /> 
        ' . $details2 . '<br /> 
        ' . $details3 . '<br /><!-- add here: --></p>
```

If you keep your same database structure, you can define into one variable after retrieving like:

```
$details = $row["details"] . '<br/>' . $row['details2'] . '<br/>' . $row['details3'];
```

And then just refer back to `$details` later on.

Why don't you want to use `nl2br()`? This would allow you to store multiple lines all into `details` column. Then you would just use:

```
$details = nl2br( $row["details"] );`
```

Here are my edits to your code:

```
<?php require_once './connections/connect_mysqli.php';
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 6 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
$i = 0;
$flatlist = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $details = $row["details"] . '<br/>' . $row['details2'] . '<br/>' . $row['details3'];
    $price = $row["price"];


    if ($i % 4 == 0) { 
        $flatlist .='<tr><td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>
        <p style=color:blue font-size=14px;>' . $product_name . '</p><br/>
            <p style=font-size:14px;>' . $details . '</p><br /> 
            <p style=font-size:14px;>$' . $price . '</p><br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><input type="button" value="Order" style=color:blue></a></td>';

    } else {

        $flatlist .= '<td width="250px" align="center"><img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg"><br/>
        <p style=color:blue font-size=14px;>' . $product_name . '</p><br />
            <p style=font-size:14px;>' . $details . '</p><br />
             <p style=font-size:14px;>$' . $price . '</p><br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><input type="button" value="Order" style=color:blue></a></td>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: ,Why don't you want to use nl2br()? This would allow you to store multiple lines all into details column. Then you would just use:

$details = nl2br( $row["details"] );` I wanted to use it but didn't know where to add it to my code. I will try it and appreciate the help.